# Webpack throws error "Unexpected token" when loading CSS

Tags: webpack

I tried to import prebuilt `semantic.css` into entry file `index.js`, webpack reported:

```
ERROR in ../semantic/dist/semantic.css
Module parse failed: /home/khoa/projects/mystack/test/semantic/dist/semantic.css Unexpected character '@' (11:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (11:0)
```

So I guessed I missed some loader to load css `@import url` statement.
I googled many hours, tried various loaders and just not done the trick.
Afterward, I noticed that whatever I put in loader-field of css file, the results are the same. (And even some stuff with any extension work fine with raw loader.)

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../semantic/dist'),
  loader: 'style!css!postcss' // whatever I put here doesn't matter
},
```

I tried to restart computer and reinstall all modules but nothing changed.
So I guess that the problem is webpack.

Comment: did you check the content of the css-file you added? It clearly states character '@' at line 11, so, it might be an import or some comment in the css-file that webpack doesnt like.

Comment: thank everyone, I've just realized that I'd resolved wrong include path, I'd thought __dirname is the exports.context dir.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you have to make a work around to make path work.

```
const path = require("path");
const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src');
```

I recommend you check the ExtractTextPlugin(https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

Add the path to your loader:

```
loaders: [
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")}
      }
    ]
```

Also you have to add the path to your loader, I prefer to do it in a constant, but this should work too.

```
   {
      test: /\.css$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../semantic/dist'),
      loader: 'style!css!postcss&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")
    },
```

Also add the resolve:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".css"],
    modulesDirectories: ["src", "node_modules"],
    root: [__dirname + path.sep + 'scripts'],
  }
```

Comment: Adding the ExtractTextPlugin should not have anything to do with that issue. That will only extract the built file as a new css-file instead of putting it in as style-tag.